# VueJS Child's Component Routing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm stuck with my first Vue application (which is a part of big ASP MVC .net app)
I have an app with three pages.

```
<router-link to="/Controller/FirstPage" class="list-numbered-item">
  FirstPage
</router-link>
... SecondPage, LastPage...

<div class="content-main">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

```
export const routes = [
    {
        name: 'Home',
        path: '/Controller/FirstPage',
        component: FirstPage,
    },
    {
        name: 'SecondPage',
        path: '/Controller/SecondPage',
        component: SecondPage,
    },
    {
        name: 'LastPage',
        path: '/Controller/LastPage',
        component: LastPage,
    },
];


let router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    linkActiveClass: "active", 
    linkExactActiveClass: "active",
    routes
});

export default router;
```

This part seems ok.

The problem is with my SecondPage.
This page contains two separate blocks and the block I'm interested in is a kind of product catalog. Click on any category provides request with `$axios` to `/Controller/GetData?key=111` and then I use response to update data() property. 
But now I know that Vue Route has a feature with child routes.

[image]

I've tried to add something like this to my route object:

```
    {
        name: 'SecondPage',
        path: '/Controller/SecondPage',
        component: SecondPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'Controller/Catalog',
                component: CatalogComponent,
            },
        ]
    },
```

And my catalog block on the SecondPage now has links for categories and router-view sections.

```
<router-link to="/Controller/Catalog/GetData?key=111">Category 1</router-link>
... Category 2, Category 3...

<div class="catalog-div">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

What I want is to choose any category and see product data in my catalog block. But any click redirects me from `/Controller/SecondPage` to `/Controller/Catalog/GetData***`. 
How can I add routing to my catalog block and stay on the SecondPage? 
Or maybe it's a wrong way to handle such usecase?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to add child `route` for the component `SecondPage`

add the `route` like follows

```
{
    name: 'SecondPage',
    path: '/Controller/SecondPage',
    component: SecondPage,
    children: [
        {
            name: 'catalog' // use name for navigation
            path: 'Catalog/:key', // using key as parameter
            component: CatalogComponent,
        },
    ]
},
```

Now inside the component

```
<router-link :to="{name:'catalog',params:{key:111}}">Category 1</router-link>
```

On clicking it will navigate to a path `/Controller/SecondPage/Catalog/111`

Note that the `key` will append with the url as parameter not as query.

It is not necessary to use name, you can use the path instead.

Comment: Great! Your explanation helped me to go further. Thank you!